# Passing argument 3 of ‘fgets’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Tags: c, string, char, shared-memory, fgets

I am a complete rookie to programming in C and have been trying to program a system that will take an integer input, perform a calculation, and tack them onto a string that will then be passed to a shared memory. Apologies if I am being an idiot but I am getting an error about an incompatible pointer type. I dont know how I can fix this error.
Edit: I apologize for the bad initial question. Full code is included

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* The size (in bytes) of shared-memory object */
    const int SIZE = 4096;

    /* The name of shared-memory object */
    const char *Obj = "Shm";

    /* The shared-memory file descriptor */
    int shm_fd;

    /* The pointer to shared-memory object */
    void *ptr;

    /* Create the shared-memory object */
    shm_fd = shm_open(Obj, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);

    /* Configure the size of the shared-memory object */
    ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);

    /* Map the shared-memory object in the address space of the process */
    ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) 
    {
       printf("Map failed\n");
       return -1;
    }

    int cal;
    char newStr[200];
    char currentStr[200];
    char *temp;
    char value;

    printf("Enter an integer");
    scanf("%d", &cal);


    /* Create a message and write it to the shared-memory object */
    /*fgets(ptr, SIZE, stdin);*/
    if (cal == 0) {
        printf("0 is not valid");
        return -1;
    }

    if (cal < 1) {
        printf("Please enter a positive int");
        return -1;
    }
    sprintf(newStr, "%d", cal);

    while (cal != 1) {
        if (cal % 2 == 0) {
            cal = cal / 2;
        }
        else {
            cal = 3 * cal + 1;
        }
        value = cal + '0';
        sprintf(currentStr, " --- %d", value);
        strcat(newStr, currentStr);
    }
    fgets(ptr, SIZE, newStr);
    printf("Writing the message to the shared memory is done! \n");

    return 0;
}
```

Due to nature of my coding environment testing and figuring out the exact nature of errors is particularly difficult.

Edit: Here is the exact error message

```
Collatz-Producer.c:84:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘fgets’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

And I had cut out the section above with `ptr` since I was confident it worked, though here is the specifics of what `ptr` equals

```
void *ptr;
ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
```

Comment: `fgets` reads from a `FILE*` passed as the 3rd argument. What is `ptr`? Do you just have it and `newStr` reversed?

Comment: Please show the exact error message and, if it includes a line number, please specify which line of your posted code that line number corresponds to.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally include a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives.

Comment: I am sorry  for the badly put together initial question. The full code is now included, I am a complete newcomer to this site

Comment: Aside: what's the reason for `value = cal + '0';` ? You would do that to change a single digit to its character value, for printing with `%c`. You can pass `cal` directly to `sprintf` here.

Comment: I could have sworn that passing cal through sprintf gave me an error before. That is now fixed for readability. Thanks

Comment: Minor: if the value entered is say `INT_MAX`, which is odd, the `* 3` will cause integer overflow.

Comment: Im not too worried about the INT_MAX section, given that this is to provide a Collatz-Sequence so all odds need to be multiplied by 3 then have 1 added to them

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with that fgets, my main guess is that you are trying to pass a file name as the third argument - is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), the function `fgets` takes 3 parameters, in this order:

1. a pointer to the memory buffer to write to
2. the size of the memory buffer
3. the `FILE *` stream to read from, for example `stdin`

The array `newStr` is not a `FILE *` stream. Therefore, it is not valid as a third parameter.

If you do not intend to read from a `FILE *` stream (such as `stdin` or a file opened with `fopen`), then you should not be using the function `fgets`.

Comment: Thanks, would there be a relatively simple way for me to copy newStr into a file. Or a better way to input the contents of newStr into the memory ptr points to

Comment: @Hexley: In order to write the contents of `newStr` to a file, you must first open the output file with `fopen` and then `fprintf` or `fputs` the contents of `newStr` to a file. For example `FILE *fp = fopen( "output.txt", "w" );` and `fprintf( fp, "%s\n", newStr );`

Comment: @Hexley: If you want to simply copy the content of `newStr` to `ptr`, then you can use [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy), like this: `strcpy( ptr, newStr );`

Comment: Thanks man, I got it to work. Thank you very much. The materials I had on hand explained this section very badly so I didn't realize that would work. Thank you